# Issue regarding mobile responsiveness

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web, frontend

https://ublostandfound.000webhostapp.com/list_of_lost_items.php

This site, when viewed on mobile has an annoying tendency to crunch up the first 4 columns and keep the last column at full length. Also, when the website is first opened, only the first 4 columns are visible. Is there a fix regarding:

A) The issue that all columns are not immediately visible and one must scroll right to view the fifth one
B) The issue that the table looks plain ugly on mobile, especially with the description crunched the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

a) What do you expect to happen? There simply isn't enough space, so of course it will push out on the right side. The reason that the last column takes full with is because it's a single word and by default those won't break. You can use the css-property word-break if you want to break a single word.

```
word-break: break-all;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

b) Getting tables responsive is always tricky. Since you tagged the question with bootstrap I would suggest looking into bootstrap's .table-responsive. This will make your table scroll horizontally but the full page will remain at 100% width.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive